# How to write cmd.exe output to console and clipboard at same time?

Tags: cmd

In cmd.exe if I run any command, I can see the output on the console, e.g, dir shows a list of all files on the console. But if I use `dir | clip`, it puts all the output on clipboard.

How to put output on console and clipboard at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a 3rd party program called `paste` to display the contents of your clipboard, which is the actual command's output:

http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/paste.html

The problem with running your command twice as suggested in dinidu's answer is that if for whatever reason the output is different on the subsequent run you will not see the same output on your console than what is on your clipboard.

So something like this:

`dir | clip & paste`

Comment: Will be useful +1. It would be great if 3rd party tool will not be required.

Comment: @PranitKothari, here's the source for [paste.cs](http://web.archive.org/web/20120523083527/http://huddledmasses.org:80/clipexe-and-the-missing-pasteexe). It's not Unicode-aware as is. You can add `Console.OutputEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false);` to make it write Unicode to the console. Also, use `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)` to ensure it gets Unicode text from the clipboard. Then if you have filenames that can't be encoded in the current codepage, you can make CMD use Unicode via `cmd /u /c dir | clip & paste`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
c:\> dir & dir|clip
```